# Prefix selected column names in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a df as follows:

```
Code              LA.Name  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
1 E06000001           Hartlepool 25 20 27 22 15 20 18 17 16 15 16 23 16 28 29 34 40 36 39
2 E06000002        Middlesbrough 46 30 30 36 18 19 19 30 31 31 24 17 37 66 64 76 60 61 48
3 E06000003 Redcar and Cleveland 39 40 24 23 26 42 33 36 31 28 20 27 32 29 45 49 49 39 33
4 E06000004     Stockton-on-Tees 38 46 33 49 26 40 23 23 35 39 35 40 33 49 67 52 36 47 49
5 E06000005           Darlington 23 31 27 21 23 17 19 29 33 19 21 22 22 28 33 39 36 33 34
6 E06000006               Halton 36 21 34 31 27 24 29 20 16 30 20 24 27 33 40 52 37 37 33
>
```

As you can see, columns 3:21 are named with numerics, I want to prefix the column names with "w". How can I do this without typing out a list of 22 new column names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by chance you are within a `dplyr` pipeline, you can also use

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  rename_at(1:19, ~str_c("w", .))
```

Answer (score 2):

```r
names(df)[3:21] <- paste0("w", names(df)[3:21])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use some regular expression to identify the numbers in the column names and modify them accordingly

```
names(df) <- gsub("([0-9]{1,})", "w\\1", names(df)
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution with `dplyr` but not needing `stringr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  rename_at(3:21, ~paste0("w", .))
```